# Find $\lim g(x_n)$ with $x_n = 3+\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> The picture shows part of function $g$ of domain $\mathbb{R}$. The
>   lines $x= 3 $ and $y = -2 $ are asymptotes of $g$. Let $x_n =
>  3+\frac{1}{n}$. The value of $\lim g(x_n)$ is:
>
> [image]

I know that $$\lim g(x_n) = g(\lim x_n)$$ and $\lim x_n = 3$, so the answer should be $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} g(x)$. However, as you can see from the graph the function is not continuous at that point and there is not limit (in other words $\lim x_n = 3^- \neq \lim x_n = 3^+$). So what should the answer be? D) ?

Comment: Consider not $g(3)$ but $g(3+\delta)$ for increasingly small $\delta$.  If $g$ were continuous, your approach would be correct, but because it is not, we can't take the shortcut.  Note that, though $g(3)$ does not exist, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 3^+}g(x)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 3^-} g(x)$ do.

Comment: @KajHansen So I can only use Heine's rule if the function is continuous?

Comment: Assuming that that rule is the one that says if $a_n \rightarrow L$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(a_n) = g(L)$, correct.  In fact, a function is continuous at a point $L$ *if and only if* the above is true for every sequence converging to $L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching from the right hand side, as $3+\frac{1}{n}> 3$, therefore you can see from the graph that you are approaching $y=2$.

Comment: Why am I approaching from the right hand side? The problem doesn't specify which side I should approach from.

Comment: Yes it does, you have $x_n=3+\frac{1}{n}$, so you are approaching 3 from the right, as $3+\frac{1}{n}>3$

Comment: Right, I understand now. Thanks.